# ADO.Net - Fetch multiple values from database

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

I'm new to Dotnet, can someone please advice - I want to write a CLASS LIBARY which will help multiple functions and they will fetch values from database. This CLASS LIBRARY would then be compiled as DLL and given to other apps to use.

Can anyone provide me link - where I can find good samples of Ado.net or can anyprovide working code which shows me how to fetch multiple or single values from database (writing all this in class library)

Regards

Comment: The [MSDN Data Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937685.aspx) would be a good place to start looking. ALso: have you considered using e.g. Entity Framework to "hide" the complexities of database access behind "nice" .NET objects? Would definitely make sense if you're starting new ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e80y5yhx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) @MSDN is a good starting point.

CodeProject features a good [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/361579/A-Beginners-Tutorial-for-Understanding-ADO-NET).

Answer (score 2):

Check this out: [Retrieving and Modifying Data in ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254937.aspx)

If you already know how to create and open a connection to database, then read this section: [DataAdapters and DataReaders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254931.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://www.w3schools.com/, it will be help lot of can you do better.

Comment: [Don't use W3Schools - it's not the best resource at all](http://www.w3fools.com)

Comment: Every one have some experience.in my experience W3schools is the best..in beginning level its very helpful to learn.